# Sublime text 2 - Change settings of plugin

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm new to Sublime and using a plugin called [ASCII-Decorator](https://github.com/viisual/ASCII-Decorator) which comes with a .sublime-settings file with a default setting:

```
{
    /* Name of the font file to use. */
    "ascii_decorator_font": "slant"
}
```

How do I change this setting?

**Edit: Where is that settings-file located?**

Comment: By editing the file to set it to what you want?

Comment: and how do I find that file? The code above is taken from the git-hub project...

Comment: Found it! Preferences > Brows Packages... > [Find the plugin folder]